# How to get random multiple rows from any table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

How to get random output of multiple rows from any table in Oracle? Also what is the meaning of (dbms_random.value)

```
select *
from (select *
      from emp
      order by dbms_random.value)
where rownum=1;
```

It gives only one random output.  How do I get multiple?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select * from (select * from emp order by dbms_random.value) where rownum<10
```

10 can be replaced by any other count of your choice

Comment: sir, what is the meaning of dbms_random.value

Comment: Its an inbuild random number generator for oracle.

Comment: I am glad i could help you. Will appreciate if you can accept the answer.